# Write the results of a "for" into a matrix/data frame in R

Tags: r, matrix

I want to write the results of a ***for*** I have designed to a matrix or a data frame at each step (and later turn that matrix or data frame into a CSV file).

My code is as follows

I want the matrix/dataframe to have **3 columns**

```
for (i in 1:100) {
  for (j in 2:100)
  {
    if (i<j) {
      temp <- pairwiseAlignment(protein_dat[i,], protein_dat[j,],substitutionMatrix=BLOSUM62,type="local")
      ###save i value into column 1 [or Seq1 in the data frame I made below]
      ###save j value into column 2 [or Seq2]
      ###save temp@score into column 3 [or into Score]
      ###go to next row of the dataframe to save the next result
    }
```

How can I do this?

EDIT #1

I have made a data frame as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(Seq1=as.numeric(),
                 Seq2=as.numeric(), 
                 Score=as.numeric(), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

EDIT #2

Is this the right way to do it?

```
for (i in 1:100) {
  for (j in 2:100)
  {
    if (i<j) {
      t <- pairwiseAlignment(protein_dat[i,], protein_dat[j,],substitutionMatrix=BLOSUM62,type="local")
      df <- rbind(df, c(i,j,t@score))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's likely to be slow. Faster would be to predimension a data structure. You have not said what class of object these values might be. If they are all numeric or all character than a matris might be more efficient.

Comment: I just tried my code, and you are right, it was very slow. All of the values are integers by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming temp stores a "scalar" (vector of length one) numeric value, try this:

```
# preallocate matrix
dataMat <- matrix(0, (100*100/2), 3)
dataRow <- 0

for (i in 1:100) {
  for (j in 2:100) {
    if (i < j) {
      # increment data row
      dataRow <- dataRow + 1

      temp <- pairwiseAlignment(protein_dat[i,], protein_dat[j,],
                                substitutionMatrix=BLOSUM62,type="local")

  dataMat[dataRow, ] <- c( i, j, temp)
}
```

If the values are accessed differently, you could make these adjustments fairly easily. After you are done, you can convert dataMat into a data.frame:

```
myDataFrame <- data.frame(dataMat)
# give it some names
names(myDataFrame) <- c("iVal", "jVal", "tempVal")
```

EDIT: Thanks to @42- for a nice code replacement.

Comment: Now that we know what kind of objects these are .... Might be faster to do this`dataMat[dataRow, ] <- c( i, j, temp)`